# makefile confusions

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use a top-level makefile. It's supposed to cd into 8 or 10 subdirectories, one by one, and make in each one. But I can't get it to work.

Here's the simplified makefile that lives in the top-level directory:

```
/home/calls/cgi>cat makefile

all:    /home/calls/cgi/chain/chain.o
        cd /home/calls/cgi/chain
        make -f /home/calls/cgi/chain/makefile
```

And here's the output from a make command:

```
/home/calls/cgi>make
cd /home/calls/cgi/chain
make -f /home/calls/cgi/chain/makefile
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/calls/cgi'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `chain.c', needed by `chain'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/calls/cgi'
make: *** [all] Error 2
/home/calls/cgi>
```

What am I doing wrong, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line in the makefile is run in its own shell, so the `cd` command only affects the line it's on.  You can, however, use continuation lines:

```
all:    /home/calls/cgi/chain/chain.o
        cd /home/calls/cgi/chain; \
        make -f /home/calls/cgi/chain/makefile
```

or just combine them on the same line:

```
all:    /home/calls/cgi/chain/chain.o
        cd /home/calls/cgi/chain; make -f /home/calls/cgi/chain/makefile
```

or if you know that `make` will always be GNU `make`:

```
all:    /home/calls/cgi/chain/chain.o
        make -C /home/calls/cgi/chain -f /home/calls/cgi/chain/makefile
```

Also, the `-f` is probably redundant, if you're in the correct directory:  `make` will try to load `GNUmakefile` (GNU `make` only), `Makefile`, and `makefile` in that order.

Comment: Thanks! That makes (err...) renders everything clear. 'preciate it.